# Node duplicating itself in List

Tags: java, list

```
public class Locations
{
    public static int LocationInArr;
    public static int LocInHeap;
    public static Locations getNext=null;

    public Locations(int a,int b)
    {
        this.LocationInArr=a;
        this.LocInHeap=b;
    }

    public static int getLocationInArr()
    {
        return LocationInArr;
    }

    public static int getLocInHeap()
    {
        return LocInHeap;
    }

    public static Locations getNext()
    {
        return getNext;
    }
  }
```

In another file:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i+=2)
{
    a=(Heap.length/k)*(i/2);
    Locations L = new Locations(a,0);
    add(L);
}
```

The above for loop is in another class which work as a List for the Location class. For some reason when I try to print the List I am creating all the Nodes in the List contains the same information.

I think I have a fundamental issue in one or more places in the code above. Any ideas?

edit:

static private Node head = null;

```
 static public void add(Locations a)
 {
     Node <Locations> pos = new Node <Locations> (a);
     if(head == null)
     {
         head = pos;
         pos.setNext(null);
     }
     else
     {
         pos.setNext(head);
         head = pos;
     }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: its supposed to create a list of Locations but for some reason all the Locations in the list are the same

Answer (score 4):

You have all the variables and methods marked as `static`. Get rid of that. `static` means that all instances share their variables instead of getting their own copies.

Comment: removed all the static 
I added references to my object in the main so it works.

beside the original question what does static do ?
when should I use it or dont ?

Comment: I have no idea why I changed everything to static and now it works!!!

thanks allot but I am dieing to know why?!?

Comment: @user3657538 If the answer solved your problem mark it as answer and then you can ask new question about static variables. But i am pretty sure there are lots of questions with answers regarding "static" keyword. try to search for static variables or variable scopes.